# BROWNIE ISSUES:NONETYPE

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3py, brownie

5:31:35 in the video, Typed the codes in exactly the same way and ran it but I keep getting this error
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

File "C:\Users\Morounfola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_*main*_.py", line 64, in main

```
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
```

File "C:\Users\Morounfola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 42, in main
active_project.load_config()
File "C:\Users\Morounfola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 462, in load_config
_load_project_config(self._path)
File "C:\Users\Morounfola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\brownie_config.py", line 222, in _load_project_config
and "cmd_settings" in values
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

This is the code;

```
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account 

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
# pass the pricefeed address to our fund me contract    

# if we are on a persistent address like rinkeby, use the associated address
# otherwise, deploy mocks
if network.show_active != "development":
   price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][
             "eth_usd_price_feed"
]
else:
   print(f"The active network is{network.show_active()}")
print("Deploying Mocks...")
mock_aggregator = MockV3Aggregator.deploy(
      18, 200000000000000000000, {"from": account}
)
price_feed_address = mock_aggregator.address
print("Mocks Deployed!")

fund_me = FundMe.deploy(price_feed_address, {"from": account}, publish_source=True)
print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")
def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this here:
[File "brownie/_config.py", line 222, in _load_project_config and "cmd_settings" in values TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281461/file-brownie-config-py-line-222-in-load-project-config-and-cmd-settings)

I had the same exact issue and it was because my brownie-config.yml file was incorrect. You can't have any blank variables in your config file.
Under networks I had:

```
networks:
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    verify: True
  kovan:
  mainnet:
```

having 'kovan' and 'mainnet' set to blank caused the error.

The solution is to either delete those two lines or comment them out like this:

```
networks:
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    verify: True
  # kovan:
  # mainnet:
```